# Unit testing when part of the class needs to be mocked

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, easymock

I have a class that I am trying to unit test.  This class extends another class that I am not interested in unit testing at this time.

The following code is an over simplification of the code I am trying to test.

```
package com.example.somePackage;
public class ApiBase {
  protected <T extends SomeClass> t getApi(Class<T> apiClass) {/* some logic*/}
}


package com.example.anotherPackage;
public MagicApiImpl extends ApiBase {
  private final MagicApiHandler apiHandler = new MagicApiHandler();

  public String doSomeStuff(String someString) {
    final BookApi bookApi = getApi(BookApi.class);
    // some logic
    return apiHandler.someMethod(bookApi, someString);
  }
}
```

I would like to test `doSomeStuff()` on `MagicApiImpl` The part I would like to mock is what comes back in `getApi()`.

At first go I tried simply creating an Instance of MagicApiImpl and setting all the behind the scenes things that happen but that started to become over complex for the scenario I want to test and the number of times I need to test it in other classes.  I will handle the testing of the logic in `getApi()` in a test of its own.

It would be helpful to use EasyMock to test this as it is what a majority of the tests for this project are written in but I would not be overly apposed to using mockito.

Edit

Okay I was reading about the Mockito.spy()  That would have been wonderful but sadly getApi is protected and in another package.  Worst case I could fall back on placing all the tests in that package but that makes it difficult track code.

Comment: This is a strong case for favoring composition instead of inheritance, as being able to inject `getApi` would make this easier to test.

Comment: @Makoto I agree.  But..  That is not helpful at this time.  In this project I am simply tasked with writing the test.  We cant all save the world and rewrite things the way they should be.

Comment: I disagree.  Making your code testable is part of testing.  As it stands, mocking this will be *incredibly* difficult since it relies on a partial mock of the instance you're testing, and as for the `final` field...that's even worse.  You are going to want to appeal to whomever tasked you with testing this to allow you to make it easier to test, which shouldn't be terribly difficult.

Comment: Check my updated answer, it is supported in Easymock with partial mocking.

Answer (score -1):

Using Easymock partial mocks your test should look like this:

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        MagicApiImpl impl = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(MagicApiImpl.class)
            .addMockedMethod("getApi")
            .createMock();
        EasyMock.expect(impl.getApi(BookApi.class)).andReturn(/**Wharever you need*/);
        EasyMock.replay(impl);
        String input = "INPUT";
        String output = impl.doSomeStuff(input);
        System.out.println("The OUTPUT is: " + output);
        EasyMock.verify(impl);
        //Run asserts here
    }
```

Reference: http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-partial